# Circular Inclusion Error, Template source files

Tags: c++, templates, circular-dependency, forward-declaration

I have two non-template classes, A and A::nested, and a class template, B.

I have a problem where a templated method in class A (A_method), defined in a .tpp file (A.tpp), requires the definition of class B since it tries to modify a member of class B inside it.

At the same time, a method in class B requires the definition of class A since one of its parameters is a class nested inside class A (A::nested).

The specific error is:

```
error: invalid use of incomplete type 'class B<>'
```

I have traced this problem to have arisen from the compilation of B.cpp, where it then #includes B.hpp, which #includes A.hpp, which #includes A.tpp, which #includes B.hpp again.

I have included the files below, they are all short and below 30 lines. Thank you.

## types.hpp (just an empty class holder for significance)

```
#ifndef TYPES
#define TYPES

class defaulttype {};
class argtype     {};
class alttype     {};

#endif // TYPES
```

## A.hpp

```
#ifndef A_HEADER
#define A_HEADER

#include "types.hpp"

template<typename = defaulttype>
class B;

class A
{
public:

    template<typename...>
    class nested{};

    B<>* data_member;

    B<alttype>* const second_data_member;

    template<typename Type>
    void A_method(B<Type>);

    A();
};

#include "A.tpp" //".tpp" is the extension I am using to indicate
                 //template source files, other places may use ".tcc" or ".ipp"
#endif //A_HEADER
```

## A.tpp

```
#ifndef A_TPP
#define A_TPP

#include "B.hpp"

#include <iostream>

template<typename T>
void A::A_method(B<T> object)
{
    data_member->next = &object;
    std::cout << object.name;
}

#endif // A_TPP
```

## A.cpp

```
#include "A.hpp"

A::A()
:second_data_member(new B<alttype>)
{}
```

## B.hpp

```
#ifndef B_HEADER
#define B_HEADER

#include "A.hpp"
#include "types.hpp"

#include <iostream>

//default arg is defaulttype, previously forward declared as such in A.hpp
template<typename T>
class B
{
public:
    B* next;
};

template<>
class B<argtype> : public B<>
{
public:
    std::string name;

    template<typename...argpack>
    void B_func_requires_nested(A::nested<argpack...>);
};

#include "B.tpp"

#endif //B_HEADER
```

## B.tpp

```
#ifndef B_TPP
#define B_TPP

template<typename...argpack>
void B<argtype>::B_func_requires_nested(A::nested<argpack...> object)
{}

#endif // B_TPP
```

## B.cpp

```
#include "B.hpp"
```

Thank you for the help.

Comment: I doubt your design is sound, but I can't really help you with that without more information about what you actually want to achieve. That said, if `nested` really needs to be inside `A`, shouldn't `B` also be inside `A` as a second nested class?

Comment: @Nelfeal I was considering that at first, but B has its own properties (in the real implementation, not in this version) which would make it better off as its own class. I will most likely move A::nested out of A and into its own namespace, as it does not 100% need to be nested, and I can find other ways of fixing the problems from that refactoring. Thank you for the advice.

Comment: Just include B.hpp in A.cpp. On the other hand I wonder what is the intent of your .tpp files: is not this file extension used for files that declare extern template instantiations?

Comment: Why B.hpp need the inclusion of A.hpp?

Comment: @Moia B.hpp needs the inclusion of A.hpp because B contains a method that takes in an argument of type A::nested, and it needs to know that that exists, so class A needs to be defined.

Comment: It's inside a template function, it doesn't need it. The necessary inclusion are needed when the object are insantatiated